Cryptography with elliptic curve 25519 in Dart
I am using Dart lang and the cryptography lib - Ed25519 class for some exploration on curve 25519, I would need to use the base point (G) to do some calculations, and I would like to ask how to get the base point of curve 25519?
Similarly, when I exploringscep256k1 algo, I used the library - pointycastle, and I can easily get the G by:
  import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
  final curve = ECCurve_secp256k1();
  final G = curve.G;

